# c# Image PropertyItems (Metadate) How do you know which number is which property?

Tags: c#, image, properties

i know the Image.PropertyItems Array holds all the metadata Information about a loaded Image.

BUT

How do you know that the e.g. ID = 20736 is the value for e.g. GIF Time per Slide?

Is there a List of all known ID´s or something?
I haven´t found anything.

Best regards

Comment: -1 for no research. Looking up PropertyItem.Id shows this list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is a list [in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms534418.aspx) [the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms534417.aspx) [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id.aspx):

```
ID     | Property tag
-------+-----------------
0x0000 | GpsVer
0x0001 | GpsLatitudeRef
0x0002 | GpsLatitude
0x0003 | GpsLongitudeRef
0x0004 | GpsLongitude
0x0005 | GpsAltitudeRef
0x0006 | GpsAltitude
0x0007 | GpsGpsTime
0x0008 | GpsGpsSatellites
0x0009 | GpsGpsStatus
0x000A | GpsGpsMeasureMode
0x000B | GpsGpsDop
0x000C | GpsSpeedRef
0x000D | GpsSpeed
0x000E | GpsTrackRef
0x000F | GpsTrack
0x0010 | GpsImgDirRef
0x0011 | GpsImgDir
0x0012 | GpsMapDatum
0x0013 | GpsDestLatRef
0x0014 | GpsDestLat
0x0015 | GpsDestLongRef
0x0016 | GpsDestLong
0x0017 | GpsDestBearRef
0x0018 | GpsDestBear
0x0019 | GpsDestDistRef
0x001A | GpsDestDist
0x00FE | NewSubfileType
0x00FF | SubfileType
0x0100 | ImageWidth
0x0101 | ImageHeight
0x0102 | BitsPerSample
0x0103 | Compression
0x0106 | PhotometricInterp
0x0107 | ThreshHolding
0x0108 | CellWidth
0x0109 | CellHeight
0x010A | FillOrder
0x010D | DocumentName
0x010E | ImageDescription
0x010F | EquipMake
0x0110 | EquipModel
0x0111 | StripOffsets
0x0112 | Orientation
0x0115 | SamplesPerPixel
0x0116 | RowsPerStrip
0x0117 | StripBytesCount
0x0118 | MinSampleValue
0x0119 | MaxSampleValue
0x011A | XResolution
0x011B | YResolution
0x011C | PlanarConfig
0x011D | PageName
0x011E | XPosition
0x011F | YPosition
0x0120 | FreeOffset
0x0121 | FreeByteCounts
0x0122 | GrayResponseUnit
0x0123 | GrayResponseCurve
0x0124 | T4Option
0x0125 | T6Option
0x0128 | ResolutionUnit
0x0129 | PageNumber
0x012D | TransferFunction
0x0131 | SoftwareUsed
0x0132 | DateTime
0x013B | Artist
0x013C | HostComputer
0x013D | Predictor
0x013E | WhitePoint
0x013F | PrimaryChromaticities
0x0140 | ColorMap
0x0141 | HalftoneHints
0x0142 | TileWidth
0x0143 | TileLength
0x0144 | TileOffset
0x0145 | TileByteCounts
0x014C | InkSet
0x014D | InkNames
0x014E | NumberOfInks
0x0150 | DotRange
0x0151 | TargetPrinter
0x0152 | ExtraSamples
0x0153 | SampleFormat
0x0154 | SMinSampleValue
0x0155 | SMaxSampleValue
0x0156 | TransferRange
0x0200 | JPEGProc
0x0201 | JPEGInterFormat
0x0202 | JPEGInterLength
0x0203 | JPEGRestartInterval
0x0205 | JPEGLosslessPredictors
0x0206 | JPEGPointTransforms
0x0207 | JPEGQTables
0x0208 | JPEGDCTables
0x0209 | JPEGACTables
0x0211 | YCbCrCoefficients
0x0212 | YCbCrSubsampling
0x0213 | YCbCrPositioning
0x0214 | REFBlackWhite
0x0301 | Gamma
0x0302 | ICCProfileDescriptor
0x0303 | SRGBRenderingIntent
0x0320 | ImageTitle
0x5001 | ResolutionXUnit
0x5002 | ResolutionYUnit
0x5003 | ResolutionXLengthUnit
0x5004 | ResolutionYLengthUnit
0x5005 | PrintFlags
0x5006 | PrintFlagsVersion
0x5007 | PrintFlagsCrop
0x5008 | PrintFlagsBleedWidth
0x5009 | PrintFlagsBleedWidthScale
0x500A | HalftoneLPI
0x500B | HalftoneLPIUnit
0x500C | HalftoneDegree
0x500D | HalftoneShape
0x500E | HalftoneMisc
0x500F | HalftoneScreen
0x5010 | JPEGQuality
0x5011 | GridSize
0x5012 | ThumbnailFormat
0x5013 | ThumbnailWidth
0x5014 | ThumbnailHeight
0x5015 | ThumbnailColorDepth
0x5016 | ThumbnailPlanes
0x5017 | ThumbnailRawBytes
0x5018 | ThumbnailSize
0x5019 | ThumbnailCompressedSize
0x501A | ColorTransferFunction
0x501B | ThumbnailData
0x5020 | ThumbnailImageWidth
0x5021 | ThumbnailImageHeight
0x5022 | ThumbnailBitsPerSample
0x5023 | ThumbnailCompression
0x5024 | ThumbnailPhotometricInterp
0x5025 | ThumbnailImageDescription
0x5026 | ThumbnailEquipMake
0x5027 | ThumbnailEquipModel
0x5028 | ThumbnailStripOffsets
0x5029 | ThumbnailOrientation
0x502A | ThumbnailSamplesPerPixel
0x502B | ThumbnailRowsPerStrip
0x502C | ThumbnailStripBytesCount
0x502D | ThumbnailResolutionX
0x502E | ThumbnailResolutionY
0x502F | ThumbnailPlanarConfig
0x5030 | ThumbnailResolutionUnit
0x5031 | ThumbnailTransferFunction
0x5032 | ThumbnailSoftwareUsed
0x5033 | ThumbnailDateTime
0x5034 | ThumbnailArtist
0x5035 | ThumbnailWhitePoint
0x5036 | ThumbnailPrimaryChromaticities
0x5037 | ThumbnailYCbCrCoefficients
0x5038 | ThumbnailYCbCrSubsampling
0x5039 | ThumbnailYCbCrPositioning
0x503A | ThumbnailRefBlackWhite
0x503B | ThumbnailCopyRight
0x5090 | LuminanceTable
0x5091 | ChrominanceTable
0x5100 | FrameDelay
0x5101 | LoopCount
0x5102 | GlobalPalette
0x5103 | IndexBackground
0x5104 | IndexTransparent
0x5110 | PixelUnit
0x5111 | PixelPerUnitX
0x5112 | PixelPerUnitY
0x5113 | PaletteHistogram
0x8298 | Copyright
0x829A | ExifExposureTime
0x829D | ExifFNumber
0x8769 | ExifIFD
0x8773 | ICCProfile
0x8822 | ExifExposureProg
0x8824 | ExifSpectralSense
0x8825 | GpsIFD
0x8827 | ExifISOSpeed
0x8828 | ExifOECF
0x9000 | ExifVer
0x9003 | ExifDTOrig
0x9004 | ExifDTDigitized
0x9101 | ExifCompConfig
0x9102 | ExifCompBPP
0x9201 | ExifShutterSpeed
0x9202 | ExifAperture
0x9203 | ExifBrightness
0x9204 | ExifExposureBias
0x9205 | ExifMaxAperture
0x9206 | ExifSubjectDist
0x9207 | ExifMeteringMode
0x9208 | ExifLightSource
0x9209 | ExifFlash
0x920A | ExifFocalLength
0x927C | ExifMakerNote
0x9286 | ExifUserComment
0x9290 | ExifDTSubsec
0x9291 | ExifDTOrigSS
0x9292 | ExifDTDigSS
0xA000 | ExifFPXVer
0xA001 | ExifColorSpace
0xA002 | ExifPixXDim
0xA003 | ExifPixYDim
0xA004 | ExifRelatedWav
0xA005 | ExifInterop
0xA20B | ExifFlashEnergy
0xA20C | ExifSpatialFR
0xA20E | ExifFocalXRes
0xA20F | ExifFocalYRes
0xA210 | ExifFocalResUnit
0xA214 | ExifSubjectLoc
0xA215 | ExifExposureIndex
0xA217 | ExifSensingMethod
0xA300 | ExifFileSource
0xA301 | ExifSceneType
0xA302 | ExifCfaPattern
```

Each of these tags is described in detail in the documentation, too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms534416.aspx

Comment: Ha true...
I am very sorry I have revied everything i have found on Google and also the MSDN Article about the Image.PropertyItems but not the PropertyItem itself .....

I think i Need some coffee, but thank you alot for the fast help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [that](https://github.com/anton-iermolenko/Photo-library-toolkit/blob/master/PhotoLibaryToolkit/Framework/ImageConstants.cs).

This is part of a larger Framework called Photo-Library-toolkit. You could base your code on this enum or maybe even use this Framework?